# Setting up Python UDP server between two computers on same Wi-Fi network

Tags: python, udp

I am trying to set up a UDP client-server connection between two laptops.

Server code:

```
import socket

def Main():
host = '8.8.8.8'
port = 8000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(2)
c, addr = s.accept()
print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
while True:
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print("from connected user: " + str(data))
    data = str(data).upper()
    print("sending: " + str(data))
    c.send(str.encode(data))
c.close()
```

client:

```
import socket

def Main():
host = '8.8.8.8'
port = 8000

s = socket.socket()
print ('Created socket')
s.connect((host, port))
print ('Connected to host')

message = input("-> ")
while message != 'q':
    s.send(str.encode(message))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print("Received from server: " + str(data))
    message = input("-> ")
s.close()
```

I was able to get this working on one laptop i.e I opened two terminals and got a working connection, but when I try and to it between two laptops, the client times out while trying to connect to the server. Based on my research as long as I don't use the IP '127.0.0.1' it should work. Any idea what could fix this?

Comment: That looks like TCP to me, not UDP.  The default values for `socket()` are `AF_INET,` and `SOCK_STREAM`.  Yet you are using `accept()`, which is not used for UDP.  Are you sure you know which protocol you want?  Presumably you are not trying to use 8.8.8.8 but a real IP address, are you?

Comment: Ya I'm using a real IP I put 8.8.8.8 because I didn't feel comfortable posting my real one. So I originally used AF_INET and SOCK_DGRAM but my project partner suggested to drop it since AF_INET is (to the best of my knowledge) used for streaming so it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: You are using `AF_INET` because that is the default.  You are not using `SOCK_DGRAM`, you are defaulting it to `SOCK_STREAM`.  But the rest of the code is appropriate for TCP/AF_INET/SOCK_STREAM, not for UDP/DGRAM.  You don't use `listen()` or `accept()` with UDP.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will make the appropriate changes to my code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is AF_INET appropriate for UDP? Or is there something else better suited for it?

Comment: Yes, but if you want UDP then your need : `sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`.  By the way this has nothing to do with your original problem, which is most likely a security issue on the operating system blocking incoming connections.